# Flask-User using REST without local DB

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a service and I would like to make the user authentication and user connections through other service, without installing a database on my presentation server.

I'm new on Flask and found this Flask User for managing, which seems quite convenient for my needs, but requires the mapping of the database. I've been trying without success to create a [SQLAlchemyAdapter](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-User/api.html) to simulate this but without success. Further more it does not seem like an appropriate solution since SQLAlchemy is for database usage.

Is it possible to have some sort of user management using a REST interface rather than a database?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this for demonstration purposes?  If so, you can use a regular ``dict`` to store users/passwords instead of a database.

Comment: Well, if I could have it for demonstration would be already good enough. Do you have any clue about how I could do that? Thanks for your answer btw.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily do-able, you can use another provides REST API to have users authenticate with their username and password (facebook, google, etc etc...)
For example:

have a user authenticate using their API:

```
def authenticate(username, password):
    """
    Example of
    function that manages authentication
    """
    global headers
    separator   = (':').encode('utf-8')
    auth_user    = username+separator+password
    headers     =   {'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % user}
    connect     = httplib.HTTPSConnection("uri")
    connect.request('GET', '/rest/auth/', headers=headers)

    response = connect.getresponse()

    statusCode = response.status

    return statusCode
```

Using flask.request you can request the data from the user /login page:

```
<body>
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Login</h1>
                        <form action="" method="post">
                                <input type="text" size="30" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="{{
                                  request.form.username }}"></br>
                                 <input type="password" size="30" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="{{
                                  request.form.password }}"></br>

                                <input class="btn btn-default" width="55" id="btn-login" type="submit" value="Login">
                            </form>
                                {% if error %}
                            <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}</p>
                                {% endif %}

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
```

Here is the python function that gets the form data:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    global username
    global password
    e = None
    try:
        if flask.request.method == 'POST':

            username    =(flask.request.form['username']).encode('utf-8')
            password    =(flask.request.form['password']).encode('utf-8')

            auth = authenticate(username, password)

            if auth == 200:
                return flask.render_template('index.html')
            else:
                print('no ooo')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return flask.render_template('login.html', error=e)
```